# Making a div 100% browser height

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked many times and I've tried the fixes provided.

I saw this post: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

and I followed what it said, make the div instead

```
height: 100%; /* Make it */
height: 100vh;
```

however my div still has a gap between the top of it and the browser window.

https://jsfiddle.net/hgs3d1n6/

What am I missing or not doing which is causing this problem? I've tried other suggestions to like making the html, body 100%.

Thanks.

Comment: `margin:0px 0px 0px 0px` add the following `css style` This is because of default margin settings just hoping so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the body and paragraph elements have a default margin. The easiest way to clear that cross browser is with:

```
body,p {
    margin:0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hgs3d1n6/1/)